# What's the right way to connect to MYSQL using mysql-connector-python?

Tags: python, mysql

According to tutorial this script for creating table should work:

```
import mysql.connector
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='kivy', password='ubuntu',
                              host='localhost', database='users',
                              auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE USERS (id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(50) NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NULL);')
```

Debugger revealed that `Segmentation Fault` is thrown when it reaches the line with `conn` variable being defined thus the line where the creds are defined.

Why do I get this error ?

**Update:**

According to Wikipedia segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts
to access restricted memory. I'm not really sure how can I use that knowledge to debug this. How can me trying to connect to mysql database
be a violation of restricted access to computer's RAM ? Just trying to connect the dots here.

Comment: What is the pip package you are using and which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7.9 and pip package mysql-connector-python latest stable release.

Comment: Does it work without `pdb.set_trace()` ? is it the same `segmentation fault` exception?

Comment: Yes, it does throw it even without setting a trace. Otherwise I would have no reason to use debugger in a first place :)

Comment: can you update python to something more recrct like 3.8,6

Comment: I'd love to but I'm working with Kivy framework and it doesn't support 3.8 well just yet.

Comment: For the time being I downgraded to Python 3.6 and things work. It's not a real solution hence I'm leaving it as a comment.